# Prove that $\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\ln n)^{- \ln n}$ converges

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

As the title suggests, I'd like to prove that the sum
$$
\sum_{n=2}^\infty (\ln n)^{- \ln n}
$$
is finite.  The root and ratio test both fail here, but [WA](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum%20n%20=%202%20to%20infinty%20%28ln%20n%29%5E%28-%20ln%20n%29) suggests that there is a comparison that can be used to show convergence.

The only thought I have is that it may help to write the terms as $e^{-\ln(n)\ln(\ln(n))}$, but this has not led me to any particular insight.  Any ideas are appreciated.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Well,

$$e^{-(\log n)(\log \log n)} = n^{-\log \log n} < n^{-2}$$

for $n > e^{e^2}$. So a comparison with $\sum \frac{1}{n^2}$ shows the convergence.

Comment: Can't believe I didn't see that.  Thank you

Answer (score 5):

There is a theorem that for a decreasing series $\sum a_n$ converges if and only if $\sum 2^k a_{2^k}$ converges. Applying that in this case gives, where I assume the log is base $2$ just to make my life easy,
$$\sum \left(\frac{2}{k}\right)^k$$ and this is easily seen to converge by root or ratio.

Comment: This is of course the [Cauchy condensation test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).  Another excellent approach!  Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

For large enough $n$, one has $\ln n > e^2$, so that $(\ln n)^{-\ln n} < e^{-2\ln n} = {1 \over n^2}$.

Answer (score 2):

By [**Cauchy condensation test**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test) we have

$$\sum 2^na_{2n}=\sum \frac{2^n}{(\log 2^n)^{\log 2^n}}=\sum \frac{2^n}{n^{(n\log 2)}\cdot{(\log2)}^{(n\log 2)}}$$

which converges for example by limit comparison test with $\sum \frac1{n^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You can use [Cauchy condensation test](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_condensation_test).