# Convergence of $\sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^{n^p}}$ for $p \ge 0$.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

I am interested in the convergence of the following sum: $\displaystyle \sum_{n = 1}^\infty \frac{1}{(\log n)^{n^p}}$ for $p \ge 0$. Clearly the sum passes the $n$th term test for convergence, is to complicated for ratio test. Applying the root test I get $\frac{1}{(\log n)^{n^{p-1}}}$ which I'm not sure is helpful. How should I proceed?

Comment: $np$ OR $n^p$ ?

Comment: Note that $n^p > \log n$, and $(\log n)^{\log n} = n^{\log \log n}$.

Comment: It is $n^p$, sorry for any confusion

Comment: @DanielFischer I get $\frac{1}{n^{\log \log n}}$. How would I finish this off? Comparison to $p$-series?

Comment: See [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/840924/prove-that-sum-n-2-infty-ln-n-ln-n-converges).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If $p=0
 $ we have $$\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{\log\left(n\right)}\geq\sum_{n\geq2}\frac{1}{n}=\infty
 $$ if $p>0
 $ we note that $$\log^{n^{p}}\left(n\right)=e^{n^{p}\log\left(\log\left(n\right)\right)}\geq e^{n^{p}}\geq n^{a}
 $$ for any fixed $a>1$ for a sufficiently large $n$, $n\geq N
 $ say. So $$\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{\log^{n^{p}}\left(n\right)}\leq\sum_{n\geq N}\frac{1}{n^{a}}<\infty.
 $$

Comment: $\sum 1/n^p$ is divergent for $0<p\le 1$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint :**

Use Cauchy's condensation test.